# Arcsine transformation for two sample proportion test

Tags: statistical-power, effect-size

I'm planning a two sample proportion test and was asked to calculate what sample size is needed to show a certain effect size at a give level of power and significance.

The book I'm using (*Statistical Power Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences*, Cohen, 1977, p. 180), notes that if we were to calculate effect size as simply $P_2 - P_1$, we would find it easier to show the same effect on baseline proportions closer to 0 or 1 vs those closer to 0.5, and for this reason [recommends first applying an arcsine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_h#Calculation).

However, when calculating the sample sizes using R's `pwr` library (based on the book), I still see that the sample sizes are dependent on how close to 0.5 the baseline proportion is.

```
library(pwr)

p1 <- seq(0.05, 0.95, 0.05)
p2 <- a + 0.02
effect_size <- ES.h(p1, p2)  # arcsin transformation

sample_size <- function(effect_size) {
  sample_size_output <- pwr.2p.test(h = effect_size, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8)
  return(sample_size_output$n)
}

plot(p1, lapply(effect_size, sample_size))
```

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: The variance is larger when $p \approx \frac12$ so absolute errors in proportions for a given sample size tend to be larger too, meaning you need a bigger sample size for the same sort of power to spot a particular absolute difference when $p \approx \frac12$.  But to spot a particular relative difference, the opposite effect occurs: you would then need a larger sample size when $p$ is close to $0$

Comment: "to spot a particular relative difference, the opposite effect occurs". Can you explain why? Also, my question is about how the arcsine transformation is supposed to ameliorate this...

Comment: The standard error of the sample mean is $\sqrt\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$. When $p=\frac12$ this is $\sqrt\frac{1}{4n}$ while when $p$ is very small it is about $\sqrt\frac{p}{n}$, which is smaller for given $n$.  But looking at the standard error divided by the mean $\sqrt\frac{1-p}{pn}$ (a measure of relative error),  when $p=\frac12$ this is $\sqrt\frac{1}{n}$   when when $p$ is very small this is about $\sqrt\frac{1}{pn}$ which is larger for given $n$